# Get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to write rampart webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

I'm trying to create a secure webservice server and client using Rampart. Web service server was created successful. But when I created client side, I got `NoSuchMethodError` in `ServiceClient.engageModule("rampart")`.

Here is my client side code:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("E:\\axis2-1.6.2\\repository", "E:\\axis2-1.6.2\\conf\\axis2.xml");

        TestStub stub = new TestStub(ctx,"http://localhost:8080/Axis2WS/services/Test");
        ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
        Options options = sc.getOptions();
        options.setUserName("test");
        options.setPassword("pass");
        options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,
                loadPolicy("policy.xml"));
        sc.engageModule("rampart");
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setA(1);
        stub.test(test);
        stub.addWS();
    }

    private static Policy loadPolicy(String xmlPath) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException{
        StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(xmlPath);
        return PolicyEngine.getPolicy(builder.getDocumentElement());
    }
```

Message Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFaultClassifier.getValueAsQName()Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.isSecurityFaultCode(RampartUtil.java:1929)
    at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.isSecurityFault(RampartUtil.java:1919)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.isSecurityFault(RampartEngine.java:306)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:73)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.ex.TestStub.test(TestStub.java:204)
    at com.ex.service.testWS.main(testWS.java:39)
```

[This](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/samples/policy/sample01.xml) is policy I used.
Thank for your help.

Comment: That's more than likely because you have a different version of Apache Axiom on your classpath than is expected by your version of the Rampart library. How did you configure your library dependencies?

Comment: First, I create dynamic web in eclipse with default java 8. Then, I copy rampart 1.7.1'lib to axis2 and Web-INF/lib folder. Is this wrong? Rampart' lib folder don't have apache axiom lib (jar file).

Comment: And I use tomcat 8 in my demo

Comment: You should also copy there any dependencies of rampart library. You can check them here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.rampart/rampart-core/1.7.1 (but those libraries may have their own dependencies and so on). I would recommend using some dependency resolving mechanism like maven or ivy.